# How to reduce unsorted array against another sorted array, keeping sorted order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6

Given an array of objects named `allItems` which is pre-sorted, but cannot be sorted again from the information it contains - what is an alternative implementation to the reduce function below that will retain the sorted order of `allItems`?

**The logic below will output:**

```
[{ id: 'd' }, { id: 'a' }, { id: 'b' }]
```

**The desired output is:**

```
[{ id: 'a' }, { id: 'b' }, { id: 'd' }]
```

```js
// NOTE: allItems is pre-sorted, but lacks the information to re-sort it
const allItems = [{id:'a'}, {id:'b'}, {id:'c'}, {id:'d'}, {id:'e'}, {id:'f'}];

const includedIds = ['d', 'a', 'b'];

// QUESTION: How to create the same output, but in the order they appear in allItems
const unsortedIncludedItems = includedIds.reduce((accumulator, id) => {
  const found = allItems.find(n => n.id === id);
  if (found) accumulator.push(found);
  return accumulator;
}, [])
```

**As mentioned in response to @Ben,** simply reversing the logic is a deal breaker for performance reasons.

Comment: what is your attempt? what have you tried?

Comment: I've thrown away all my ideas in the conceptualization phase as being unwieldy and turned to the internet to look for suggestions, and then to StackOverflow when that failed me.

Comment: If I understand what you've written, your code will output it exactly backwards. So you can just reverse the list afterwards. Alternatively, you can push to the front (take care as this is less efficient on normal JS lists, you may have to implement your own queue)

Comment: @Ben the problem with that approach is that `allItems` contains potentially thousands of items, whereas `includedIds` is maybe a dozen - and the `allItems.find()` will stop when it's found its match. Simply reversing it would work, except it would be an enormous performance hit. Apologies, should have mentioned that from the start.

Comment: "*simply reversing the logic is a deal breaker for performance reasons*" - not sure what you mean by "reversing the logic"?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have here is that your code reverses the list. You can simply push to the front of the list instead, and the original order will be maintained.

Unfortunately, pushing to the front of a list is slower, it's O(n) rather than O(1). It looks like `Array.prototype.unshift` is supposed to be [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6195753/3513171), but it's still O(n) according to this [blog](https://medium.com/@brayce1996/time-complexity-analysis-of-javascript-array-unshift-74930aaa2f6). Assuming that the number of found elements is small you won't notice any performance issues. In that case, replace `push` with `unshift` like so:

```
// NOTE: allItems is pre-sorted, but lacks the information to re-sort it
const allItems = [{id:'a'}, {id:'b'}, {id:'c'}, {id:'d'}, {id:'e'}, {id:'f'}];

const includedIds = ['d', 'a', 'b'];

// QUESTION: How to create the same output, but in the order they appear in allItems
const unsortedIncludedItems = includedIds.reduce((accumulator, id) => {
  const found = allItems.find(n => n.id === id);
  if (found) accumulator.unshift(found);
  return accumulator;
}, [])
```

Otherwise, these are your options:

1. Create a wrapper around this object that reverses the indexes rather than the array. This can be done with a function like this:

   const getFromEnd = (arr, i) => arr[arr.length - 1 - i]

Note that this can be replaced with `arr.at(-i)` in new browser versions (last few months). This could be encapsulated within a class if you're feeling OOP inclined.

2. Remember to manually invert the indices wherever you use this array (this will be bug-prone, as you may forget to invert them)
3. Reverse the array. As shown in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j6w7rbe0/), even with 10,000 elements, the performance is not bad. Assuming this isn't a hotpath or user-interactive code, I think that even 100,000 is probably fine.

Answer (score 1):

## Update

> ***Example B* will use the index of the input array to sort the filtered array.**

Try `.filter()` and `.include()` to get the desired objects and then `.sort()` by each object's string value. See ***Example A***.

Another way is to use `.flatMap()` and `.include()` to get an array of arrays.

> ```
> // each index is from the original array
> [ [15, {id: 'x'}], [0, {id: 'z'}], [8, {id: 'y'}] ]
> ```

Then use `.sort()` on each sub-array index.

> ```
> [ [0, {id: 'z'}], [8, {id: 'y'}], [15, {id: 'x'}] ]
> ```

Finally, use `.flatMap()` once more to extract the objects and flatten the array of arrays into an array of objects.

> ```
>  [ {id: 'z'},  {id: 'y'},  {id: 'x'} ]
> ```

See ***Example B***

### Example A (sort by value)

```js
const all = [{id:'a'}, {id:'b'}, {id:'c'}, {id:'d'}, {id:'e'}, {id:'f'}];

const values = ['d', 'a', 'b'];

const sortByStringValue = (array, vArray, key) => array.filter(obj => vArray.includes(obj[key])).sort((a, b) => a[key].localeCompare(b[key]));

console.log(JSON.stringify(sortByStringValue(all, values, 'id')));
```

---

### Example B (sort by index)

```js
const all = [{id:'a'}, {id:'b'}, {id:'c'}, {id:'d'}, {id:'e'}, {id:'f'}];
const values = ['d', 'a', 'b'];

const alt = [{name:'Matt'}, {name:'Joe'}, {name:'Jane'}, {name:'Lynda'}, {name:'Shelly'}, {name:'Alice'}];
const filter = ['Shelly', 'Matt', 'Lynda'];

const sortByIndex = (array, vArray, key) => array.flatMap((obj, idx) => vArray.includes(obj[key]) ? [[idx, obj]] : []).sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]).flatMap(sub => [sub[1]]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(sortByIndex(all, values, 'id')));
   
console.log(JSON.stringify(sortByIndex(alt, filter, 'name')));
```

Comment: OP said `all` is pre-sorted, so the last `sort` method call is not needed.

Comment: @jsejcksn OP  `includedIds` are out of order hence the `sort()`

Comment: No, it is an error to sort the result of the filter. OP used `/^[a-z]$/` for IDs just as an example, but said `all` is pre-sorted and the sort order cannot be determined from the available information.

Comment: @jsejcksn Understood, updated answer -- see ***Example B***

Comment: @zer00ne thanks for your answer! It seems like the performance implications of _**Example B**_ are similar to the performance implications of inverting the original reduce function to `allItems.reduce(...)` though - Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating over the `includedIds` (in the wrong order) and seeing whether you can find them in `allItems`, just iterate over `allItems` (which is the right order) and see whether you can find their ids in `includedIds`:

```
const allItems = [{id:'a'}, {id:'b'}, {id:'c'}, {id:'d'}, {id:'e'}, {id:'f'}];

const includedIds = ['d', 'a', 'b'];

const includedItems = allItems.filter(item => includedIds.includes(item.id));
```

Comment: For what it's worth, if performance is as key as OP seems to suggest, turning `includedIds` into a set may be wise. I suppose that also depends on how large it ends up being.

Comment: @Ben I was wondering to mention that, but OP wrote in a comment on the question that "*`includedIds` is maybe a dozen*" so I don't think it's worth it

Answer (score 0):

Why not just reverse the logic, Filter out the ids which not suppose to be includes.

```js
// NOTE: allItems is pre-sorted, but lacks the information to re-sort it
const allItems = [
  { id: "a" },
  { id: "b" },
  { id: "c" },
  { id: "d" },
  { id: "e" },
  { id: "f" },
];

const includedIds = ["d", "a", "b"];

const findElms = (items, includedIds) => items.filter((n) => includedIds.includes(n.id))

console.log(findElms(allItems, includedIds));
```